# How to load csv file in hive table?

Tags: hive

I create table in hive and load csv file also from hdfs but when try to perform select query on created table I am getting results in encrypted format, can you please provide solution for this.

```
create table if not exists studentsinforamtion(
  studentnumber string ,
  universityname  string,
  collegename   string,
  studentname string, 
  branch string, 
  percentage string,
  areaters string,
  rankatuniversity INT,
  eligibleforcompnay string,
  selectedcompanylist int) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
stored as textfile;

load data inpath '/user/root/jobportal/studentinfo.ods' overwrite into table studentsinforamtion;

select * from studentsinforamtion limit 5;
```

ERROR:

```
OK
PK5:�C�l9�.mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheetPK5:�C�{C44meta.xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
<office:document-meta xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2
```

Comment: This might be useful: http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/05/17/hive-insert-and-dump-csv-with-map-datatype.html

Comment: a csv-serde is nice when dealing with csv-files, since often a field may contain the delimiter char which makes the default serde rather unusable

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your file is not pure comma-separated-file (or tab-separated as I see from your table's delimiter). It has some opendocument metadata "mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheetPK5:�C�{C44meta.xml". Try to save your doc in .csv format or use simple text editor to create needed spreadsheets.

FYI - 'NULL' in select result usually means that column type and value type are different  - e.g. you have table with column types (int, int, int) and you've downloaded file into it with values (15, 23, userinfo) - select should return 15, 23, NULL. Hive doesn't check types of values during upload, so pay attention to them.